# Waiting for multiple actions before proceeding in redux-saga

Tags: javascript, redux-saga, saga, take, es6-generator

Assume that you have a saga that fetches a list of items. For each fetched item you also need a companion object.
The pseudo-code below fetches some users from an API and for each user is emitting a new action to fetch her avatar.

```js
function* fetchUsers() {
  try {
    const users = yield call(getUsers)
    yield all(
      users.map(({id}) => id).map(id => put(fetchUserAvatar(id)))
    )

    yield put('FETCH_USER_SUCCESS')
  } catch(e) {
    yield put('FETCH_USER_FAILURE')
  }
}
```

I would like to emit `FETCH_USER_SUCCESS` only when all avatars have been fetched i.e. `fetchUserAvatar` saga has emitted either `FETCH_USER_AVATAR_SUCCESS` or `FETCH_USER_AVATAR_FAILURE`.

So, I implemented the following solution:

```js
function* fetchUsers() {
  try {
    const users = yield call(getUsers)
    yield all(
      users.map(({id}) => id).map(id => put(fetchUserAvatar(id)))
    )

    for(let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
      yield take(['FETCH_USER_AVATAR_SUCCESS', 'FETCH_USER_AVATAR_FAILURE'])
    }

    yield put('FETCH_USER_SUCCESS')
  } catch(e) {
    yield put('FETCH_USER_FAILURE')
  }
}
```

which feels a little ugly to me. Is there any effect such as `takeN` or a similar technique where I can wait for N actions to be emitted before proceeding?
Or is there any alternative solution for the above problem?

Comment: I can write up an answer for you, basically you need to compare by `id` to `take` the right action.  Where do you `take` the action that you `put` by `fetchUserAvatar(id)`?  Where are you sending the data to the store?  I would think in `FETCH_USER_SUCCESS` but you aren't showing any `payload`.  Is our goal here just to fetch the user *and* the avatar, or is the user a disregarded intermediate and we only care about the avatars?

Comment: @LindaPaiste 
Q: Where do you `take` the action that you `put` by `fetchUserAvatar(id)`?
A: Assume that a second saga is taking `FETCH_USER_AVATAR_REQUEST ` action
Q: Where are you sending the data to the store? I would think in `FETCH_USER_SUCCESS` but you aren't showing any payload.
A: Correct. Assume that a payload is sent on `FETCH_USER_SUCCESS` action